# Data types (arithmetic operators) in snowflake transformation

Tags: sql, etl, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Good day I have a question about my non-functional code. As you can see I want to connect some tables with union. I would like to have records from marketing applications, but I need to use some arithmetic operators. The problem is that even though I set datatype to Number, the code does not work (but in another transformation there is no problem) and reports an error "Numeric value '' is not recognize" I'm sending a full code, but problem is this line:

```
(case when skl."impressions_sklik" = 0 then 0
  when skl."clicks_sklik" = 0 then 0
  when skl."clicks_sklik" = '' then 0
  when skl."impressions_sklik" = '' then 0
  ELSE (iff(skl."clicks_sklik" = 0 or skl."clicks_sklik" IS NULL or 
     skl."clicks_sklik" = '', 0, skl."clicks_sklik")  / 
    iff(skl."impressions_sklik" = 0 or skl."impressions_sklik" IS NULL 
     or 
    skl."impressions_sklik" = '', 0, skl."impressions_sklik"))
    END) as "CTR"
    FROM "sklik" skl
```

or this:

```
(case when skl."impressions_sklik" = 0 then 0
   when skl."clicks_sklik" = 0 then 0
   when skl."clicks_sklik" = '' then 0
   when skl."impressions_sklik" = '' then 0
   when skl."clicks_sklik" IS NULL then 0
   WHEN skl."impressions_sklik" IS NULL then 0
   ELSE (skl."clicks_sklik" / skl."impressions_sklik")
   END) as "CTR"
```

or this, nothing works:

```
(case when skl."impressions_sklik" = 0 or skl."clicks_sklik" = 0 then 
skl."clicks_sklik" / skl."impressions_sklik" = 0
   when skl."clicks_sklik" = '' or skl."impressions_sklik" = '' then 
skl."clicks_sklik" / skl."impressions_sklik" = 0
   when skl."clicks_sklik" IS NULL or skl."impressions_sklik" IS NULL 
then skl."clicks_sklik" / skl."impressions_sklik" = 0
   ELSE (skl."clicks_sklik" / skl."impressions_sklik")
END) as "CTR"
FROM "sklik" skl
```

Can you help me with that pls?

Full code:

```
SELECT
adw."adwords" as "Type",
adw."campaignID_adwords" as "campaignID",
adw."impressions_adwords"as "impression",
adw."CTR_adwords" as "CTR"
FROM "adwords" adw
UNION
select
skl."sklik" as "Type",
skl."Campaign_id_sklik" as "campaignID",
skl."impressions_sklik" as "impression",
  (case when skl."impressions_sklik" = 0 then 0
   when skl."clicks_sklik" = 0 then 0
   when skl."clicks_sklik" = '' then 0
   when skl."impressions_sklik" = '' then 0
   ELSE (iff(skl."clicks_sklik" = 0 or skl."clicks_sklik" IS NULL or 
skl."clicks_sklik" = '', 0, skl."clicks_sklik")  / 
iff(skl."impressions_sklik" = 0 or skl."impressions_sklik" IS NULL or     
skl."impressions_sklik" = '', 0, skl."impressions_sklik"))
END) as "CTR"
 FROM "sklik" skl
UNION
select
fad."facebook_ads" as "Type",
fad."cam_campaign_id_facebook_ads" as "campaignID",
fad."cam_impressions_facebook_ads" as "impression",
fad."cam_ctr_facebook_ads" as "CTR"
FROM "facebook_ads" fad
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two separate problems here.

First, if "impressions_sklik" and "clicks_sklik" are defined as NUMERIC, it is invalid to compare them to the text value ''. That is where you are getting the "Numeric Value Not Recognized message"

Second, if "impressions_sklik" is NULL, you will encounter a divide-by-zero issue in your CASE statement.

To fix both of the issues, please rewrite as the much simpler following expression:

```
(case 
    when skl.impressions_sklik = 0 or skl.impressions_sklik IS NULL then 0
    when skl.clicks_sklik = 0 or skl.clicks_sklik IS NULL then 0
    ELSE ( skl.clicks_sklik  / skl.impressions_sklik)
END) as CTR
```